# How to reset password on rails api? [Not using devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

So I'm trying to right a recover password mechanism for my rails api and I've hit a wall.

After doing some research, I came up with a way to implement it. It returns the values like it work but the password does not get reset and I don't why.

My user table looks like this:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "middle_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  end
```

And my way of resetting the password goes:
From controller:

```
...
def reset
        token = params[:token].to_s

        if params[:email].blank?
            return render json: {error: 'Token not present.'}
        end

        user = User.find_by(reset_password_token: token)

        if user.present? && user.password_token_valid?
            if user.reset_password!(params[:password])
                render json: {status: 'ok'}, status: :ok
            else
                render json: {error: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        else
            render json: {error: 'Link not valid or expired.'}, status: :not_found
        end
    end
...
```

Then model:

```
...

 def password_token_valid?
        (self.reset_password_sent_at + 4.hours) > Time.now.utc
    end

    def reset_password!(password)
        self.reset_password_token = nil
        self.password = password
    end
...
```

Is this the right way to implement this?
Is this the safest way to implement this?

Note: I only tested this on production, this is due to the limitation of my development environment to send emails.

Comment: a) you never call save or update after setting the password, b) don't do this. Unless you really just want to spend all your time writing authentication code, use devise or another gem.  This is just the first of many gotchas.

Comment: So would that be a `self.save!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just updating the values in memory and never persisting them to the database.

```
def reset_password!(password)
  update!(
    password: password,
    reset_password_token: nil
  )
end
```

> Is this the safest way to implement this?

No. Reinventing the authentication wheel is one of the most common reason apps get hacked.

Comment: Thanks... I wish someone had told me that before I decided to authenticate authentications.